# Why Does WMI (Capturing) Boot Image Require "wpeutil initializenetwork" To Be Ran?

Tags: networking, windows-7, 64-bit, wds

I don't get why I have to take the extra steps to run "wpeutil initializenetwork" before my NIC card is turned on and working within the WMI Capture (WinPE) GUI.  I have the drivers added to the image and I still have to press Shift+F10, then type that command to get networking running.  I don't install/add any new drivers, I just enable/initialize the network card.

Currently I'm manually pushing out images to PCs but soon I plan on using an unattended answer file and automating the process.  I'm sure this is going to give me issues...  Is there any way to fix this so that the network card is automatically initialized?